# Make FireBug 1.7.3 always "break on error" or on "debugger;" encounter

Tags: debugging, firebug

Firebug was breaking on encountering a "debugger;" statement in one file, yet running the same file copied to another location in the same browser was making it skip "debugger;"

How can I make it break all the time?  Always?

P.S.  I moused-over the bug icon and it says "break on next" or "break on all errors", I can't remember now, since I think it changed when I clicked it, and this is what finally got Firebug to stop on "debugger;".  But now when I mouse over. it just always says "break on next" no matter how many times I click it.  Exactly how do you use this icon?!

Thanks,

Comment: Got it...I had to reinstall the latest version to 1.11.1 from http://getfirebug.com/. So I am running Firefox version 18.0.1 with FireBug version 1.11.1.  Now everything works great!